# When published in azure function QueryWorkspaceAsync returns status 403

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm using QueryWorkspaceAsync to access azure logs from code to work with. While locally everything runs smoothly and I am able to work with tables I get from it. Now I decided to create time trigger azure function that would run once a day and send me report from specific things found in logs. I tested function locally and it run smoothly. But when I published it I get error:

`Azure.RequestFailedException: The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation Status: 403 (Forbidden) ErrorCode: InsufficientAccessError Content: {"error":{"message":"The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation","code":"InsufficientAccessError","correlationId":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"}}`

Here is sample of function if it is any help:

```cs
public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 0 8 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Function was triggered at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
    try
    {       
        Response<LogsQueryResult> response = await client.QueryWorkspaceAsync(workspaceId, "AppTraces | where AppRoleName == \"servicesmonitoring\" | summarize Count = count() by OperationName | order by Count desc", new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)));
        
        log.LogInformation($"Successfully got query #1.");
    }
}
```

I have no idea what could be problem since function is published in same workspace as logs I'm trying to access are. I was also unable to find any articles mentioning problem I encountered.

Comment: Which IDE did you develop it with locally?

Comment: Visual studio 2022

Comment: Ok, so you’re logged in to Azure through VS, yes? Did you know that? If so, it uses your auth to access the resources when you debug locally. You need to look into managed identities and how they work. Your function app will need access to the resources it’s trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by Skin I was able to resolve this issue by adding Function Application to Access control (IAM) of accessed Log Analytics workspace.